# How to check if user uploaded a photo ReactJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I want to style different cards if the user picked a photo or not. If they picked a photo then I want to have a `width: 600px` but if not I don't want that image thumbnail and I want to have a `width` of `300px` and I want to show only text if the user didn't upload a photo. How can I know if the user picked a photo or not? Please help.

This is the code:

```
       return (

  <div className="card" style={{ width: "600px" }} key={i}>
    <div className="card-body">

      <img src={`${
        process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
        }/post/photo/${post._id}`}
        alt={post.title}
        className="img-thumbnail mr-4 float-left rounded mb-3"
        style={{ height: "400px", width: "300px", objectFit: "fill" }}
      />

      <p className="card-text" style={{ color: "#darkslategray", fontSize: "15px" }}>
        {post.body.substring(0, 50)}
      </p>
      <br />
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by picked a photo?

but from what I can tell from the code you could do something like this

```
const [photoPicked, setPhotoPicked] = useState(false)
```

// call setPhotoPicked somewhere to toggle the state above

```
return (
    <div>
        <div className="card" style={{ width: photoPicked ? '600px' : '300px' }} key={i}>
        <div className="card-body">

        <img 
            src={`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/post/photo/${post._id}`}
            alt={post.title}
            className="img-thumbnail mr-4 float-left rounded mb-3"
            style={{ height: "400px", width: "300px", objectFit: "fill" }}
        />

        <p className="card-text" style={{ color: "#darkslategray", fontSize: "15px" }}>
        {post.body.substring(0, 50)}
        </p>
        <br />
    </div>

)
```

basically you need to set the state of `photoPicked` to be true or false and based off that, change the width

Comment: hi `onError={<img src="user-icon.png" alt=" " style={{width:"0px",height:"0px",display:'none'}}></img>}
                                   

                                    onLoad={<img className="img-thumbnail mr-4 float-left rounded mb-3"   style={{ height: "400px", width: "300px" ,objectFit:"fill"}}></img>} `. I tried doing this and it works just the way I want except for body card being too big and broken image icon do u know how can I fix

Comment: call a function inside `onError` that will change the width. i.e. in my example `onError={() => setPhotoPicked(!photoPicked)`

Comment: why don't you use this package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images-upload

Answer (score 0):

You can use image's onLoad event for this purpose also you should put some logic into onError event. If you want to show selected image in the image element you can use `URL.createObjectURL`.

if you think isPicked as a state which you mutate in someLogic and loadLogic.

```
<image src={isPicked && URL.createObjectURL(file.data)} onError={someLogic} onLoad={loadLogic} />
```

Ex:

```
const [imageSrcIsSet, setImageSrcIsSet] = useState(true);

<Card style={{ width: imageSrcIsSet ? "600px" : "300px" }} > 
<img src={imageSrcProperty} style={{ width: imageSrcIsSet ? "300px" : "0px" }} onError={()=> setImageSrcIsSet(false)} onLoad={() => setImageSrcIsSet(true)} /> 
</Card>
```

Comment: `onError={<img src="user-icon.png" alt=" " style={{width:"0px",height:"0px",display:'none'}}></img>}
                                   

                                    onLoad={<img className="img-thumbnail mr-4 float-left rounded mb-3"   style={{ height: "400px", width: "300px" ,objectFit:"fill"}}></img>}` this is what I did but it gives me a broken image icon and I can't style the card width as well how can I fix that

Comment: Nope you can't render in this way. You must do something like this:
`const [imageSrcIsSet, setImageSrcIsSet] = useState(true);`
.
.
`<Card style={{ width: imageSrcIsSet ? "600px" : "300px"  }} >
<img src={imageSrcProperty} style={{ width:  imageSrcIsSet ? "300px" : "0px"  }} onError={()=> setImageSrcIsSet(false)} onLoad={() => setImageSrcIsSet(true)} />
</Card>`

Comment: I'm getting this broken image icon

Comment: If you share some updates from your code, we can check it again.

Comment: `  <div className="card" style={{ width: imageSrcIsSet ? "400px" : "150px" }}   key={i}> <div className="card-body"><img src={`${ process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL }/post/photo/${post._id}`}
     alt={post.title}
                                    style={{ width: imageSrcIsSet ? "350px" : "0px" }}
                                   
                                onError={()=>this.setState({setImageSrcIsSet:false})}
                                 onLoad={() => this.setState({setImageSrcIsSet:true})}
                                
                                /> `

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [image, setImage] = useState('');  

    const [previewImage, setPreviewImage] = useState();          


 <label htmlFor="image">Image</label>
                    <input 
                    type="file" 
                    name="image"
                    onChange={fileUploadHandler}
                    />

                    <img src={previewImage} className={styles.previewImage}/>
```

*this is the function for changing image value*

```
const fileUploadHandler = (e) => {
        const url = e.target.files[0];
        setImage(url);
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(url);
        fileReader.onload = () => {
            setPreviewImage(fileReader.result);
        };
    };
```